# How to get the mean of same name elements of list

Tags: r, list, mean

I have made a function that runs a bootstrapped regression (with plm). I've managed to get a list, that contains a list for every repetition. Inside that sub-list, there are two coefficients each one with its name.

So I want to know if I can get the mean of each coefficient, by calling it just for the name.

The minimal example I could do was with three repetitions so the list looks like this:

```
> dput(b)
list(list(capital = 0.185108300831744, labor = 0.342750547967331), 
    list(capital = 0.219370274172395, labor = 0.302455636315905), 
    list(capital = 0.191813145986764, labor = 0.317630069307932))
```

So the desired result is a list with the mean for capital and the mean for labor, like this:

```
> dput(result)
list(capital = 0.1987639, labor = 0.3209454)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a base R solution:

```
b <- list(list(capital = 0.185108300831744, labor = 0.342750547967331), 
          list(capital = 0.219370274172395, labor = 0.302455636315905), 
          list(capital = 0.191813145986764, labor = 0.317630069307932))

my_names <- c('capital', 'labor')
result <- lapply(my_names, \(x) mean(sapply(b, '[[', x)))
names(result) <- my_names

result

$capital
[1] 0.1987639

$labor
[1] 0.3209454
```

Alternately, we can take advantage of the fact that lists can be treated as data frames:

```
result <- colMeans(do.call(rbind, lapply(b, as.data.frame)))

  capital     labor 
0.1987639 0.3209454
```

Answer (score 1):

- You can use `purrr::transpose` to swap your list to `capital` and `labor` then get the `mean`

```
purrr::transpose(b) |> lapply(\(x) mean(unlist(x)))

$capital
[1] 0.1987639

$labor
[1] 0.3209454
```

Comment: `|>` is this? R version 4 syntax?

Comment: Yes ; it is from `R 4.1` same as `magritter` pip operator `%>%` , use can use `lapply(purrr::transpose(b) , function(x) mean(unlist(x)))` for old versions .

Answer (score 1):

A `base R` option with `unlist/tapply`

```
with(stack(unlist(b)), as.list(tapply(values, ind, FUN = mean)))
$capital
[1] 0.1987639

$labor
[1] 0.3209454
```